# AxisFault: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException

Tags: soap, wsdl, apache-axis, soap-client, wsdl2java

we are using drupal soapservice for webservices. while we are trying to call soapservice, it returns the results but axis2 throws the following error...

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: element text content may not contain START_ELEMENT 
 at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430) 
 at com.chm.api.login.client.DrupalSoapStub.fromOM(DrupalSoapStub.java:12249) 
 at com.chm.api.login.client.DrupalSoapStub.userLogin(DrupalSoapStub.java:1408) 
 at SocketClient.main(SocketClient.java:144) 
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: element text content may not contain START_ELEMENT 
 at com.chm.api.login.client.DrupalSoapStub$UserLoginResponse$Factory.parse(DrupalSoapStub.java:59804) 
 at com.chm.api.login.client.DrupalSoapStub.fromOM(DrupalSoapStub.java:11473) 
 ... 2 more 
Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: element text content may not contain START_ELEMENT 
 at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.SwitchingWrapper.getElementText(SwitchingWrapper.java:981) 
 at javax.xml.stream.util.StreamReaderDelegate.getElementText(StreamReaderDelegate.java:100) 
 at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.getElementText(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:100) 
 at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.debug.XMLStreamReaderValidator.getElementText(XMLStreamReaderValidator.java:76) 
 at com.chm.api.login.client.DrupalSoapStub$UserLoginResponse$Factory.parse(DrupalSoapStub.java:59770)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had faced a similar issue, but not exactly the same as you are facing.  I had resolved the issue by adding the following dependency in the class path:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
   <artifactId>jaxws-rt</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.5</version>
</dependency>
```

I am not sure whether it works for your problem or not, but you can try it.